Adding an average line to a gradient legend
I would like to add a line to a legend gradient bar.
That's how my legend looks:
enter image description here
What I want is this:
enter image description here
My code:
main_map <- ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = parties_ger_plz, aes(fill = np), color = "white", linewidth = 0.045) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(
        name = NULL,
        na.value = "#9DBF9E",
        labels = scales::label_number(scale = 1, suffix = " %", accuracy = 1),
        colors = c("#9DBF9E", "#FCB97D", "#A84268"),
        guide = guide_colorbar(
            frame.colour = "black", # Rahmen um die Farbskala
            frame.linewidth = 0.3, # Breite des Rahmens
        )
    ) +
    geom_sf(data = geo_data_ger_adm_states, linewidth = 0.25, color = "black", fill = "transparent") +
    coord_sf(expand = FALSE) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
        plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "cm"),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.3, "cm"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 6)
    )

big_map <- ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = parties_ger_plz, aes(fill = np), color = "white", linewidth = 0) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(
        name = NULL,
        na.value = "#9DBF9E",
        labels = scales::label_number(scale = 1, suffix = " %", accuracy = 1),
        colors = c("#9DBF9E", "#FCB97D", "#A84268"),
        guide = guide_colorbar(
            frame.colour = "black", # Rahmen um die Farbskala
            frame.linewidth = 0.3, # Breite des Rahmens
        )
    ) +
    geom_sf(data = geo_data_ger_adm_states, linewidth = 0.25, color = "black", fill = "transparent") +
    coord_sf(expand = FALSE) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
        plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "cm"),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.3, "cm"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 6)
    )

# ggsave("test2.png", plot = main_map)

big_map <- big_map +
    annotate(
        "rect",
        xmin = 7.8,
        ymin = 52.5,
        xmax = 10.4,
        ymax = 54,
        fill = NA,
        color = "black",
        size = 0.3
    ) +
    theme(
        axis.title = element_blank(), # Entfernt Achsentitel
        axis.text = element_blank(), # Entfernt Achsenbeschriftung
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), # Entfernt Achsenstriche
        panel.grid = element_blank(), # Entfernt Gitterlinien
        legend.position = "none",
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white")
    )

noth_west_germany <- main_map +
    coord_sf(
        xlim = c(7.8, 10.4),
        ylim = c(52.5, 54),
        expand = FALSE
    ) +
    annotation_scale(location = "bl", text_cex = 0.7, ) +
    labs(title = "Herkunft der Beteiligten vor den\nBremer Amtsgerichten (2007-2019)") +
    theme(
        legend.position = c(1, 01),
        legend.justification = c(1, 1),
        legend.box.just = "right",
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "lightblue"),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 1),
        axis.title = element_blank()
    )


final_map <- noth_west_germany %>%
    ggdraw() +
    draw_plot(
        {
            big_map
        },
        x = 0.635,
        y = 0.05,
        width = 0.4,
        height = 0.4
    ) +
    coord_fixed() +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
        plot.background = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "cm")
    )

Does anybody have an idea?
I tried something like this:
mean_np <- mean(parties_ger_plz$np, na.rm = TRUE)

# Hauptkarte mit Mittelwert in der Legende
main_map <- ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = parties_ger_plz, aes(fill = np), color = "white", linewidth = 0.045) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(
        name = "Klagequote (%)",
        na.value = "#9DBF9E",
        labels = scales::label_number(scale = 1, suffix = " %", accuracy = 1),
        colors = c("#9DBF9E", "#FCB97D", "#A84268"),
        guide = guide_colorbar(
            frame.colour = "black",
            frame.linewidth = 0.3,
            ticks = TRUE,
            ticks.colour = "black",
            barwidth = 0.5,
            barheight = 10,
            title.position = "top"
        )
    ) +
    geom_sf(data = geo_data_ger_adm_states, linewidth = 0.25, color = "black", fill = "transparent") +
    coord_sf(expand = FALSE) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
        legend.text = element_text(size = 6),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 7),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.3, "cm")
    )

# Mittelwert in der Legende markieren
final_map <- main_map +
    guides(
        fill = guide_colorbar(
            draw.ulim = TRUE,  # Zeichnet obere Grenze
            draw.llim = TRUE,  # Zeichnet untere Grenze
            ticks = TRUE,
            ticks.colour = "black",
            title.position = "top",
            title.hjust = 0.5,
            label = TRUE
        )
    ) +
    # Mittelwert als Annotation hinzufügen
    annotate(
        "segment",
        x = 0.5, y = mean_np, xend = 1.5, yend = mean_np,
        color = "blue", size = 0.5, linetype = "dashed"
    )

but this just destroys my whole plot.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Using the recently on CRAN published legendry package which prvoides

additional guide functionality to the ggplot2 ecosystem

you can achieve your desired result like so:
library(ggplot2)
library(legendry)

p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = cty)) +
  geom_point()

key <- key_manual(
  aesthetic = 22,
  label = "average"
)
sec_guide <- compose_stack(
  primitive_ticks(key = key, theme = theme(
    legend.ticks = element_line(color = "red", linewidth = 1),
    legend.ticks.length = unit(-.6, "cm")
  )),
  primitive_labels(key = key)
)

p +
  scale_colour_viridis_c(
    guide = guide_colbar(
      second_guide = sec_guide
    )
  )


And here is another example using scale_fill_gradientn as in your example code:
library(ggplot2)
library(legendry)

nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)

p <- ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = 100 * AREA))

key <- key_manual(
  aesthetic = 100 * mean(nc$AREA),
  label = "average"
)

sec_guide <- compose_stack(
  primitive_ticks(key = key, theme = theme(
    legend.ticks = element_line(color = "black", linewidth = 1),
    legend.ticks.length = unit(-.6, "cm")
  )),
  primitive_labels(key = key)
)

p +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    name = NULL,
    na.value = "#9DBF9E",
    labels = scales::label_number(
      scale = 1, suffix = " %",
      accuracy = 1
    ),
    colors = c("#9DBF9E", "#FCB97D", "#A84268"),
    guide = guide_colbar(
      second_guide = sec_guide,
      theme = theme(
        legend.frame = element_rect(
          colour = "black", linewidth = 0.3
        )
      )
    )
  )


